# How can I access Firestore data from within a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is my first time using Cloud Functions. I'm trying to make a simple call to access all the businesses stored in my Firestore collection, but when I try to log the results, I always get an empty array.

All things w/ Firebase/store are set up properly, collection name is listed properly, and have confirmed access to the database by logging db. Is there something obviously wrong with my code here? Thanks!

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.updateBusinessData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const db = admin.firestore()

  const businessesReference = db.collection('businesses')
  var businesses = []

  const getBusinesses = async () => {
    const businessData = await businessesReference.get()

    businesses = [...businessData.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data()}))]

    for (let business in businesses) {
      console.log(business)
    }

    response.send("Businesses Updated")

  }

  getBusinesses()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getBusinesses` function is `async`: you then need to call it with `await`. Then, since you use `await` in the Cloud Function you need to declare it `async`.

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.updateBusinessData = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    try {
        const db = admin.firestore()

        const businessesReference = db.collection('businesses')
        var businesses = []

        const getBusinesses = async () => {
            const businessData = await businessesReference.get()

            businesses = businessData.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

            for (let business in businesses) {
                console.log(business)
            }
        }

        await getBusinesses();
        // Send back the response only when all the asynchronous
        // work is done => This is why we use await above
        response.send("Businesses Updated")
        
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }

});
```

---

You are probably going to update docs in the `for (let business in businesses)` loop to use `await`. Change it to a `for … of` loop instead as follows:

```
for (const business of businesses) {
    await db.collection('businesses').doc(...business...).update(...);
}
```

### Update following the comments

Can you try with this one and share what you get from the console.logs?

```
exports.updateBusinessData = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    try {

        console.log("Function started");
        const db = admin.firestore()

        const businessesReference = db.collection('businesses');
        const businessData = await businessesReference.get();
        console.log("Snapshot size = " + businessData.size);
        const businesses = businessData.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        for (const business of businesses) {
            console.log(business);
        }
        response.send("Businesses Updated")

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Renaud Tarnec ! I tried this too, but it didn't work either. Same question I asked Tim above - do you think its possible that I could not be connected to my Firestore? Everything I've seen indicates that I am, but I guess I can't completely rule that out as the problem.. As I said in the question, I logged to console my db, and it prints data about my project as I would expect. Thanks much!

Comment: Can you add a `console.log()` at the top of your Cloud Function? Just to be sure you call it correctly. The Cloud Function itself should not have any problem to call Firestore. I'll update the answer with a more simple code (without a `getBusinesses`function): can you give a try?

Comment: I tried this, and I had the output show correctly. I'm viewing this all in the Firebase Emulator Suite, but I get the logging as expected. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you deploy the function? Just to check if it's a side effect from the emulator.

Comment: This is my result. 

`Beginning execution of "_myregion_-updateBusinessData"
Function started
Snapshot size = 0
Finished "_myregion_-updateBusinessData" in ~1s`

Comment: Do you see `Snapshot size = 0`=> It means that there is no document in the `businesses` collection. You need to debug that. Wrong collection? Wrong Firestore instance? ...

Comment: The collection is definitely correct, although I'm not exactly sure how to check for the wrong Firestore instance. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to deploy the Cloud Function and see what happens when not using the emulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235199/discussion-between-carter-foughty-and-renaud-tarnec).

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the way you were processing the docs and I'm getting proper data from firestore.

```
exports.updateBusinessData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();

  const businessesReference = db.collection("businesses");
  const businesses = [];

  const getBusinesses = async () => {
    const businessData = await businessesReference.get();

    businessData.forEach((item)=> {
      businesses.push({
        id: item.id,
        ...item.data(),
      });
    });

    // used for of instead of in
    for (const business of businesses) {
      console.log(business);
    }

    response.send(businesses);
  };
  
  getBusinesses();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim ! I tried this, but unfortunately no dice. Do you think its possible that I could not be connected to my Firestore? Everything I've seen indicates that I am, but I guess I can't completely rule that out as the problem..

Comment: Are you working with the emulator? If so, maybe you are accidentally connected to the production resources?  I tested this code in the emulator.

Also, are you 100% certain there is data at this path? No typo?

db.collection('businesses')

Comment: I'm absolutely sure the path is correct. I am using the emulator, although I'm not sure how to check whether I'm connected to the production resources. Any tips there? Thanks!

Comment: I know it does provide a warning message about it being a production resource when you call the function.